# Regex for decimals with maximum length

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not sure if this is possible with regex. I'll try to use regex, but if not possible I'll switch to a double validation.

My database (postgresql) accepts `decimal` as 15,6 (Maximum of 15 digits with a maximum of 6 decimals), so if I have 10 integer digits, I can have 5 decimals digits. The decimal separator is ignored.

I currently have this regex (Comma is the decimal separator):

`^\d{1,15}(\,\d{1,6})?$`

It does not verify the total length, only the numbers to the left.
But since the user can also type dots (thousands separator), I have this monster:

`^((\d+)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})+)|(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})(\,\d{3})+))((\,\d{4})|(\,\d{3})|(\,\d{2})|(\,\d{1})|(\,))?$`

This one does not accept more than 3 decimals. I can edit this one to accept 6 decimais, but I still can't validate the total length.

**Is it possible to verify the total length of the number? Ignoring the dots and comma.**

The regex should accept:

`1234567890,123456`

`1.234.567.890,123456`

And of course any other middle values:

`1.234,12`, `1,0`, `1`...

Comment: What language are you using for this? Tagging that might help get this more attention.

Comment: Alright, it's c#. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Decimals are numeric, not text values. They don't have separators. If you want to *validate* a value you can use UI validators and Data Annotations at the DTO level, etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to validade an input inside a `TextBox`.

Comment: While it is certainly possible to come up with a regex that matches your case, it will likely not be a simple one. Maybe use [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) with NumberStyles to parse the input and do some manual checking. If the `TryParse` succeeds you can do pretty much anything. For example you could `ToString` it and split on the decimal sign to check string lengths. It's not a one-liner, like regex, but will be much simpler to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}){0,4}|\d{1,15})(?:,\d{1,6})?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d)%7b0%2c4%7d%7c%5cd%7b1%2c15%7d)(%3f%3a%2c%5cd%7b1%2c6%7d)%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=1234567890%2c123456%0d%0a1.234.567.890%2c123456%0d%0a234.567.890.123.456%0d%0a234.567.890.123.456%2c46&o=m)

The integer part only allows 1 to 15 digits (or 5 groups of 3-digit chunks separated with `.` digit grouping symbol), and optionally followed with a comma and 1 to 6 decimal digits.

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}){0,4}|\d{1,15})` - 2 alternatives:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3}){0,4}` - 1 to 3 digits, followed with 0 to 4 sequences of a dot (`\.`) and 3 digits (`\d{3}`)
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{1,15}` - 1 to 15 digits
- `(?:,\d{1,6})?` - optional sequence (1 or 0 occurrences) of a comma followed with 1 to 6 digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: The total length can't be > 15, including decimals digits. So here's a small change: `^(( your regex ){1,15})?$` But I may be wrong.

Comment: I doubt that `^(( your regex ){1,15})?$` is what you need, it will match much more... However, you have more insight into your data, glad I could help.

Comment: How can it match much more?

Comment: I do not know what the final regex you meant. If you enclose it with another pair of `()` and set a `{1,15}` quantifier, it will match 1 to 15 occurrences of what my regex matches.

Comment: OH, that's a mistake, I meant to verify the total length. I forgot that. :O

Comment: If you need to verify the *total* length, with all dots and commas, you need a positive lookahead: `^(?=.{1,15}$)` (to set it 1 to 15 characters). If you need up to 15 digits in the integer part and up to 6 in the decimal part, that is what my regex is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Just throwing this out as an alternative. In my opinion you shouldn't use a Regex in this case. Why? Because the Regex that will actually match the question won't be easy to understand.

Much simpler solutions exist for the problem. Take for example this:

```
var input = "1.234.567.890,123456";
var input2 = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d,]+", "");

var split = input2.Split(',');
var totalLength = split[0].Length + split[1].Length;
```

Nothing fancy. But it works, unlike the other solutions provided until now.

But what about different culture settings? Different cultures use different thousand separators. That's where something like [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad(v=vs.110).aspx) can come in:

```
var input = "1.234.567.890,123456";

var style = NumberStyles.Number;
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");

double result;
if (double.TryParse(input, style, culture, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("It worked!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not valid");
}
```

The above works because the `nl-NL` culture uses the format. Set it to `en-US` and it will fail.

Neither really use a Regex to get the job done, but they can still produce the desired result.

Comment: I'm using something like this, using a regex to verify thousands and decimals separators and using `text.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "")` to get the total length. Thanks, I'll stop using regex for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^[\d\.\,]{1,15}([\.\,]\d{0,6})?$`

Comment: This would allow 123456789012345,123456.

Comment: Nice, it ignores the dots and comma, but it accepts `123456789011111,123456`, ignoring the length limit.

Comment: @NickeManarin what are you trying to do? .NET has validators and data annotations that allow you to validate decimal values without converting them to text and having to deal with negatives, thousand and decimal separators

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Text validation with a maximum length for decimals digits and validation of total length with and without thousands separators.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d{0,15})([\.\,]\d{0,6})?$
```

- Group 1:
  any number with max length = 15
- group 2:
  any number with max length of two, preceded by `,` or `.`

Comment: Sorry but this answer does not address the question, is a duplicate, or cannot be improved.