# Need help to build regular expressions C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

I want to write a RegEx to validate a text line on some conditions. Those are -

1. 1st 6 characters must be number
2. Then 3 characters must be Uppercase letter
3. Then other characters are decimal number, but max length in 15 (Decimal part). Decimal part can have comma (,) in it and 2 decimal point after that comma.

I am trying to build and ended like this:

```
^\d{6}[A-Z]{3}\d{1,15}[\d,]{0,3}$
```

Here is some example

```
123456ABC124                  valid
123456BCD123456789123,00      valid
090929BDT888,00               valid
123456BCD1234567891234,00     invalid
```

It works fine but I can't specify decimal length can't be more than 15

Comment: try with this https://regexr.com/

Comment: Also, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840723/regex-for-decimals-with-maximum-length

Comment: When you say max length of 15, does that include the decimal point? Is the number of digits after the decimal point fixed at 2 or can it be 0,1,or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following what you say, the solution is:

```
^\d{6}[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{1,15}$|\d{1,14},$|\d{1,13},\d$|\d{1,12},\d\d$)
```